# No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty' error in JBOSS

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, javax.validation

i have a SpringBoot version '**2.3.9.RELEAS**E' application.

Jboss version: **jboss-eap-7.1**

successfully deployed the application to **jboss**. when i try to login through my web application, an error occured.

```
No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty' validating type 'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for 'emailAddress'
```

validation class is as below

```
@Getter @Setter public class Login  {
@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter email address.", groups = ValidationOrder.Step1.class)
private String emailAddress;
    
@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter password.", groups = ValidationOrder.Step1.class)
private String password; }
```

I have added "jboss-deployment-structure" to 'WEB-INF' directory.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
      <exclusions>
         <module name="javax.validation.api" />
      </exclusions>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

### pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.1.Final</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Error still remains. An idea?

Its working fine in **Netbeans 8.2** + **Apache Tomcat**

Answer (score 0):

You should use spring-boot-starter-validation instead of adding the libraries.

So remove:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.1.Final</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also remove the version of lombok. This is already defined by the spring boot parent